# Firebase Storage Non-Default Buckets Always Return 403 on IOS/Android Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-storage

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fuck_my_life/firebase_options.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
     
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {

      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(

        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,

        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(

        child: Column(
       
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            FutureBuilder<String>(
                future: FirebaseStorage.instance
                    .refFromURL("gs://_____-a5183/f/8704182.jpg")
                    .getDownloadURL(),
                builder: (c, s) {
                  return Text(s.data?.toString() ?? "تحميييل");
                }),
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

So, here my project is simple, it is just retrieving data from the storage bucket, when I make a call from the sdk (android) to default bucket it will send and retrieve the link

Otherwise when I call with other bucket as specified (not default) it will yield 403, even tho my rules for the bucket are:

```
rules_version = '2';

service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {

    match /{allPaths=**}{
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```